# Html.ActionLink very slow

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4 and the Razor View Engine.

I have a `Html.ActionLink("Title", "Action")` call which is called in a foreach-loop with ~200 items and this takes about 550ms to complete. If I replace the ActionLink with a simple string it only takes ~50ms --> the Html.ActionLink needs ~500ms for 200 iterations!

**Is there a way to speed this up?**

I have 5 of these in my loop so my page needs >3s to render...
Release build and no debug attribute in the web.config does not help.

Comment: I had trouble with Html.RenderPartial that was very slow. As soon as I compiled in release and running on IIS, it was very fast.

Comment: Are you sure you're only calling `Html.ActionLink("Title", "Action")` and not something more complex? Also, do you have many routes registered? What machine are you running the code on?

Comment: Try building a specific route for this action and using `RouteLink` instead of `ActionLink`. There is a lot less code to build a link with that. And when I say **a lot less code** I'm talking about the code written by Microsoft.

Comment: @AndreLoker: Good tip - I had a custom route which did some DB queries -> without that it already only takes about 1/3 of the time...

Comment: try to add the controller name also in the ActionLink

Comment: OffTopic: If querying the DB a lot in your route handler makes things slower, perhaps you could consider caching it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I combined a few of the tips from the comments to achive a reduction from ~3s to ~250ms for the rendering of the complete page. The biggest changes where:

- Cache the DB queries from my custom route (-> 2/3 time saving per call)
- "Pregenerate" the links and only replace parts of it:
   I did a `@{ var link = Html.ActionLink("_USER_", "Edit", new { id = "_ID_" }); }` before the foreach loop and in the loop something like `@link.Replace("_ID_", user.UserId.ToString())` (you can't use String.Format, as the `Html.ActionLink()` escapes `{0}` to `%7B0%7D`

Comment: thought you might be interested to see this (about 9 minutes in) https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Azure-Friday/Profiling-Live-Azure-Web-Apps-with-Application-Insights